# Simulating Weibull distributions from vectors of parameters in R

Tags: r, simulation, distribution, weibull

I have a vector of 365 shape parameters and a vector of 365 scale parameters from Weibull distribution.

How can I simulate 365 values from corresponding parameters in R?

The background of my question is: I have daily average wind speed which follows a Weibull distribution of unique parameters. Now, I would need to simulate daily wind speed from the data.

Comment: Sounds like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16998809/r-with-weibull-parameters-k-and-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `rweibull` function. Btw, do you want just one simulated value per parameter pair?

Anyhow, this should do it for `nobs` number of observations. You can choose n=1 as well.

```
simulations <- mapply(rweibull, shapes, scales, MoreArgs=list(n=nobs))
```

where `shapes` is your vector containing the shape parameters, and similarly `scales` is the vector containing the scale parameter values.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried simulation<-mapply(rweibull,c(2,1.5),c(6,8),list(n=1)) and the results seem to be in matrix...I'm a little confused since I'm expecting to get two values in this case. coudl you help me understand?

Comment: You forgot the `MoreArgs` part there. See this:

    simulation <- mapply(rweibull, c(2, 1.5), c(6, 8), MoreArgs=list(n=1))